# mouseover and mouseout events firing on children

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, prototypejs, dom-events, scriptaculous

The code:

```
<div id="Navigation" 
    onmouseover="new Effect.toggle('Drop_Down','slide',{duration: 0.8});" 
    onmouseout="new Effect.toggle('Drop_Down','slide',{duration: 0.8});">
    <div id="Drop_Down">
        <% include Navigation %>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I mouseover the `Navigation` the `Drop_Down` div slides down, and if I mouseout it slides up.

The problem is if I mouseover the child `Drop_Down` div it also slides up.

Does anyone know how I can fix that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`mouseenter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536945(VS.85,loband).aspx) and [`mouseleave`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536946(VS.85,loband).aspx) events instead *[new in Prototype 1.6.1](http://www.prototypejs.org/2009/9/1/prototype-1-6-1-released)* (but not new in IE). You have to move your inline event handlers out of your markup to do this:

```
<div id="Navigation">
    <div id="Drop_Down">
        <% include Navigation %>
    </div>
</div>
```

And setup the events in script:

```
<script>
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    $('Navigation')
        .observe('mouseenter', function() {
            new Effect.toggle('Drop_Down','slide',{duration: 0.8})
        })
        .observe('mouseleave', function() {
            new Effect.toggle('Drop_Down','slide',{duration: 0.8})
        })
})
</script>
```

Unlike `mouseover` and `mouseout`, these events do not bubble from child elements. They are fired on the exact element you bind them to, solving your issue nicely.

Comment: so it works, thank you. i would vote your answer but i have less then 15 reputations...
greets chris

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate, generic (not Prototype-specific) answer

This is caused by Event Bubbling. More info, including how to cancel it in child nodes, here:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html